# UnZip files to the previous folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I am using this code to extract files using **Ionic.Zip.dll**

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("E:\\Hello\\Hi\\Photos.zip"))
{
    zip.ExtractAll("E:\\Hello\\Hi\\", ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverWrite);
}
```

This is working fine and extracting everything to : "E:\Hello\Hi\Photos" folder, by creating another Photos folder inside it.

Here all images in photos.zip folder is extract and kept in a new folder created "Photos"

I want all this to be extracted to "E:\Hello\Hi\" only NOT another Photos folder.

Comment: Do you really extract it just into Hello/Hi? If there is a Photos folder inside the zip, it would extract to Hello/Hi/Photos. I tried your code and it works well for me. Maybe show us how your zip file looks inside?

Comment: Zip file structure ... `E:/Hello/Hi/Photos.zip` ...

Comment: You probably misunderstood me. What structure is IN Photos.zip?

Comment: in Photo.zip..I have lots of images...like 1.jpg, 2.jpg....and so on...simple files in side zip

Comment: Are you sure that these images are directly in Photos.zip? Or is there any folder first?

Comment: yes..exactly like that

Comment: I tried your code and it works as it should work. No side effects. I'm not sure if you provided us with correct information.

Comment: Did you mean that,,,your ran the same code..and all files from photo.zip is extracted to E:/Hello/Hi/ ??? AND NOT E:/hello/hi/photos/ ??\

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I ment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("E:\\Hello\\Hi\\Photos.zip"))
{
    zip.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = true;
    zip.ExtractAll("E:\\Hello\\Hi\\", ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverWrite);
}
```

Try something like this, the FlattenFoldersOnExtract will ignore any possible folders in the zip.

Comment: My problem is not to remove any folder...I want the zip to be extracted to ..E:/Hello/Hi/  instead of E:/Hello/Hi/Photos

Comment: Did you try the code? It works on my end. If I comment out the FlattenFoldersOnExtract section, it will place it in a Photos folder. If I have it uncommented, it will place the files in the Hi folder

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("E:\\Hello\\Hi\\Photos.zip"))
{
   foreach (ZipEntry e in zip.SelectEntries("*.*"))
   {       
       e.Extract("E:\\Hello\\Hi\\", ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverWrite);
   }
}
```

Comment: all extract to 'e:\Hello\Hi\Photos' ? At archive all files located at root?